# Create zip archive and stream it to ftp server

Tags: php, ftp, stream, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to create a zip file from local files and stream it directly to an ftp (without writing the zip to disk first). I have no problems with zipping itself but it seems like the ZipArchive class doesn't recognize the ftp stream wrapper.

The following code is the simplest thing I could come up with that will illustrate the problem

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
var_dump($zip->open('ftp://[username]:[password]@[hostname.net]/public_html/test.zip', ZipArchive::OVERWRITE));

$zip->addFile(realpath('/input.txt'), 'input.txt');

var_dump($zip->close());
```

The `$zip->open` call returns `true` while `$zip->close` returns `false`. I can't find a way to get an error message or something that can be more specific than just `there is an error`. The question is what am I doing wrong, or I can't do these kind of stuff with the ZipArchive class.

Comment: You can try a `try`, `catch` block .. maybe there is an `Exception`

Comment: No exceptions are thrown. I have error reporting for everything and an unhandled exception would eventually throw an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested your code on my Ubuntu system and I can confirm that it does'nt work.
By using the "strace" utility, I've seen that the PHP is handling the "$filename" argument as if it was a local file name, as you can see below:

```
lstat64("/var/www/test/ftp://myuser:mypass@127.0.0.1/tmp/test.zip", 0xbfcbb008) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat64("/var/www/test/ftp://myuser:mypass@127.0.0.1/tmp", 0xbfcbaeb8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat64("/var/www/test/ftp://myuser:mypass@127.0.0.1", 0xbfcbad68) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat64("/var/www/test/ftp:", 0xbfcbac28) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The "/var/www/test" prefix is the path of my PHP test script.
So, it seems that effectively the ZipArchive::open() method cannot handle URL filenames.
Looking at the PHP source code, and I've discovered that the ZipArchive::open() method calls the "[zip_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.zip-open.php)" function.
The PHP manual page for the "[fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)" function states:

> If filename is of the form "scheme://...", it is assumed to be a URL
>   and PHP will search for a protocol handler (also known as a wrapper)
>   for that scheme. If no wrappers for that protocol are registered, PHP
>   will emit a notice to help you track potential problems in your script
>   and then continue as though filename specifies a regular file.

[This post](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php#85763), found in the PHP manual page for the "[stream_wrapper_register](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php)" function, states that zip_open() ignores custom stream wrappers, but the above test shows that it also ignores standard stream wrappers.
It's also true that neither [ZipArchive::open() manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php) nor the zip_open manual page explicitly say that the "$filename" parameter can be a URL.

Comment: Thank you for the information and even looking at the PHP source! I'll just write it to a file and send it over the ftp after that.